# Share current html response(as is) with user input intact

Tags: html, go

I am trying to achieve something similar to the Go Playground's [`share`](https://play.golang.org/) button.
When a button called `share` is clicked, the current HTML response is saved into a file. That also includes everything a user can see.

**What I can do so far**
- I can successfully save an HTML page into a file.
- I can get and save a whole page from a URL using HTTP Get.

**Caveats**
- I can't save a current webpage I am working on.

This is my code so far for getting remote URLs:

```golang
func HTTPGet(url string, timeout time.Duration) (content []byte, err error) {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    ctx, cancel_func := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    request = request.WithContext(ctx)

    response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if response.StatusCode != 200 {
        cancel_func()
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("INVALID RESPONSE; status: %s", response.Status)
    }

    return ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
}
```

Hopefully this will not involve messing with the DOM manually.

Comment: If you want to save the current web page as it is displayed to the client (with the current form values, etc.), you have to do that with Javascript on the client side. You can get the document, somehow serialize it and send it to the server to save it. Alternative is to generate the HTML page on the server side again, but that will not contain data user entered, or any dynamically generated HTML on the client side. Af course, you can save only the data to reconstruct the page (form values, etc), and regenerate the HTML as needed.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, this project actually uses GopherJs.  So I can interact with javascript. If you have an example in javascript, I would like to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I can save the div data into a server database, then later reconstruct the page with that data using normal Golang response.

Comment: I don't have an example, sorry. Never worked with GopherJs. I'd do this myself by saving form data and page state only and reconstructing the page as needed.

Comment: This is actually the most relevant approach. If you can put that in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few ways this can be done, with some cooperation from the client.

If you want to save the current web page as it is displayed to the client (with the current form values, etc.), you have to do that with Javascript on the client side. You can get the document, serialize it in some form and send it to the server to save it.

Alternative is to generate the HTML page on the server side again, but that will not contain data user entered, or any dynamically generated HTML on the client side.

Another way is to use Javascript on the client side to collect page state including form values and data representing any dynamically generated content, send it to the server to save, and reconstruct the page as needed.